# QGIS symbol resources

Tags: qgis, symbology, sld

Anyone have any good resources you can point me to find additional symbol libraries that are published for qgis/sld?

My preliminary search has turned up a lot of plugs for the Resource Sharing plugin, but unfortunately, there really isn't much in terms of complex line styles.

For context, I'm looking for line styles along the lines of these:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can access the following repositories that have an additional symbology that you can use in QGIS

https://style-hub.github.io/

http://qgis-hub.fast-page.org/styles.php

[Credit to Klas Karlsson](https://twitter.com/klaskarlsson/status/1288937372235816962)

Comment: +credit to Klas Karlsson

Answer (score 3):

On the web I found this source:

- https://github.com/afrigeri/geologic-symbols-qgis

You can try to create your symbols with Inkscape and add them with this plugin

https://mariosmsk.com/2019/10/03/inkscape2symbol-qgis/

On the other hand, you can create symbols like the one you show in the image, with the symbology options that QGis gives you, you add other layers of symbols, using lines of markers, managing the orientation of the markers.